# Why is the computer memory reported as full, while processes use much less memory?

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, process, task-manager

My Windows 10 PC has 16GB RAM installed. Yet everything is soooo slowww.

In Task Manager, I see that the memory utilization is almost always at 98%-99% level. Yet, the aggregate memory consumption of all reported processes is far less than 16GB. More like 2.5GB.

Below is the capture of task manager's Performance and Processes table. The Details tab is similar.

Why is the reported memory consumption much higher than the detailed report? This causes a constant need for paging and memory swapping (to an SSD! but still very slow), which renders the system extremely non-responsive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This has been asked many times and should be closed as a duplicate. You likely have a memory leak caused by a third party driver, use something like RAMMap (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) to diagnose. Rebooting should temporarily fix it. Often people will try to tell you that this is normal behaviour, despite your computer being almost unusable. This is because they misunderstand how memory management works and how cached RAM does not affect reported usage

Comment: Also.. when you say `to an SSD! but still very slow`.. this will wear out your SSD!